# How to get a value of the closest td with class on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, closest

I have table rows with data and buttons. http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/nuIkd

Each button corresponds to each row, also when you click a button it changes class names from `hide` to `un_hide` the next step is to retrieve the text value of the td with class `contact_name` in the row that the clicked button belongs too.

Table structure:

```
<tr>
  <td class="contact_name" style="padding: 7px 0;">
    Name 1
  </td>
  <td>
      <button class="btn_hide">Hide</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="contact_name" style="padding: 7px 0;">
      Name 2
  </td>
  <td>
      <button class="btn_hide">Hide</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Using this jQuery, it will get ALL text values of .contact_name in all the rows

```
var name = $('.contact_name').text();
```

So I tried this to get the text value of the 'closest' .contact_name td

```
var name = $(this).closest('.contact_name').text();
```

However that returns blank for me :(

How would you get the **Name 1** value by clicking the **first Hide button**?

Comment: `$(this).closest('td').siblings('.contact_name').text()`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`.contact_name` is not parent from the clicked button.

```
var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.contact_name').text();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
var name = $(this).closest('td').prev('.contact_name').text();
```

Or

```
var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.contact_name').text();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9GwY8/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = $(this).closest('tr').children('.contact_name').text();
```